# c# I want Select Where Datetime Show Crystal Report But not Show Data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
MyCommand.Connection = myConnection;
MyCommand.CommandText = "select * from vwProfit Where OrderDateGet= '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "'";
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
myDA.Fill(myDS, "vwProfit");

rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
frm.Show();
```

Who can Edit Code Me, 
I want select where date but not show Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both datetime in same format and then try.

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "select * from vwProfit Where Convert(varchar,OrderDateGet,103)= convert(varchar,'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "',103)";
```